# How to use third, fourth etc. decimal values in a calculator

Tags: r

I want to calculate the Body Mass Index for four persons and store the results as object XY and append it to a data frame. That works fine so far, but I only manage to do this with rounding the results

```
   Body Mass Index <- round(as.numeric(data[, 4], 
   digits=2)/(as.numeric(data[, 3])/100)^2)
   Body Mass Index
   data <- as.data.frame(cbind(data, Body Mass Index))
   data
```

How can I do the same but round the resulting values to third or fourth decimal place? I know it has something to do with round and obviously I changed it, but the other options do not work...

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

The argument digits in `round` defines how many digits will be shown. Becareful because certain objects ou function round the data just for the printing. Here is an example.

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### Example Data

```
df <-
  #Random data
  tibble(
    height = rnorm(10,1.7,sd = .2),
    mass = rnorm(10,70)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    # Calculating index
    bmi_index = mass/(height^2),
    bmi_index_round4 = round(bmi_index,4),
    bmi_index_round3 = round(bmi_index,3),
    bmi_index_round2 = round(bmi_index,2)
    )
```

### Output

```
> df$bmi_index
 [1] 21.69752 33.96611 19.23116 23.32622 20.93689 26.45366 23.50817 33.12299 27.41969 22.49677
> df$bmi_index_round4
 [1] 21.6975 33.9661 19.2312 23.3262 20.9369 26.4537 23.5082 33.1230 27.4197 22.4968
> df$bmi_index_round3
 [1] 21.698 33.966 19.231 23.326 20.937 26.454 23.508 33.123 27.420 22.497
> df$bmi_index_round2
 [1] 21.70 33.97 19.23 23.33 20.94 26.45 23.51 33.12 27.42 22.50
```

Comment: Hi Vinicius, when I try to apply this in my above mentioned formula I would just set in    Body Mass Index <- round2(as.numeric(data[, 4], 
   digits=2)/(as.numeric(data[, 3])/100)^2)
   Body Mass Index
   data <- as.data.frame(cbind(data, Body Mass Index))
   data ? but it says could not find function "round2"